# how to open dll and exe files in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, dll, exe, ubuntu-12.04

I have a few dll and exe files. My laptop has ubuntu version 12.04 installed in it. Can anybody give me suggestion what should I be doing now so that the file runs on Ubuntu?

Comment: You could try Wine ... http://www.winehq.org/ or a VM... or compile it as a proper Linux executable if you have the source?

Answer (score 2):

You can install Wine from the Ubuntu repository and try to execute the files with it. AFAIK many Windows programs can be executed with an out-of-the-box Wine installation, for some, you have to take extra steps (like adding some libraries) and some do not run with it.

Another option would be setting up a virtual machine with a Windows installation in it for executing the programs you need.